# Passing Values from Form to Form

Tags: .net, database, vb.net, global-variables

I need to pass a data bound integer that is from a populated list in a combo box from one for to another. In form 2 I need the rest of the fields to be populated based on that integer that is passed. I can pass the integer, however when form2 opens it keeps bringing up the value that is top of the list in my data base. All my textboxes and comboboxes are populated by drag and drop datasource.

`studentNo` is my global variable

Form1 code:

```
studentNo = cboStudents.SelectedText
```

Form2 code:

```
cboStudentNo.SelectedText = studentNo
```

Insted of `.selectedText` I have also tried `.Text` and `.SelectedItem`but to no avail.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Integers are not bound.  You might have controls bound to values from a DB, but not vars. Create a method on the receiver form to allow you to pass/push *data* to it

Comment: Also, `SelectedText` probably doesnt so what you think it does.  Read the Intellisense tip that pops up when you hold the mouse over it

Comment: @Plutonix What are you suggesting by creating a method so?

Comment: No problem @Plutonix, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, if `studentNo` is an integer, then you should turn on Option Strict.  This code wont compile:

```
studentNo = cboStudents.SelectedText
```

You are assigning text/string to an integer.  Next, `SelectedText` probably doesnt do what you want; Intellisense tells us that it: `Gets or sets the text that is selected in the editable portion of a ComboBox.`.  It is not the selected item in the list.

For a bound combobox of students, assuming the `DisplayMember` is the name and `ValueMember` is the ID, you want `SelectedValue`.  You could get it in the `SelectedValueChanged` event:

```
' ToDo: check if selectedvalue is nothing to avoid NRE
studentNo = Convert.ToInt32(cbo.SelectedValue)
```

The conversion is necessary because the `SelectedValue` will be `Object` and you want to assign it to an integer.  To pass that to the other form when it is needed, create a method to receive it:

```
' on form 2
Public Sub DisplayStudentInfo(id As Int32)
    ' wonderful things
End Sub
```

Then just pass the info.  Assuming `frm2` is an instance of Form2:

```
' push/pass/convey the desired ID to the other form:
frm2.DisplayStudentInfo(studentNo)
```

Alternatively, you could create a property on one form or the other as the means to expose it.  This can be (too) passive: if `Form1` exposes it as a prop, the other form(s) have no way to know when it changes.  Using a method (`Sub`) allows you to add code to take action when a value is passed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!!  It is not necessary for me to have student no as an integer, would it make it less complicated if I changed it to a string?

Comment: It ought to be the same type as the column it represents in the DB.  Given the name, implied function and the OP, I assume int32.

Comment: My bad, It's actually set as string in my DB!

Comment: Is it the PK/ID for a student table?

Comment: No it is not, I have a seperate ID PK which i do not use

Comment: Hard to imagine how something that doesnt uniquely identify a record/student is important, but string, int, long or anything else, it doesnt matter, its just data.